# How to upgrade the Existing node js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

Currently we are using node Js version 8, if I switch that to node Js 16, application is not working, and it shows lot of errors.
How to upgrade the existing node js application to latest version of node? what are steps we need to follow?

**Error:**

```
 { inspect: [Function: inspect] }
[2022-04-18 11:18:27.085] [ERROR] app - Could not load adapter sails-db2 try npm install sails-db2
[2022-04-18 11:18:27.097] [INFO] app - Running ORM initialization, please wait...
C:\Chanel\Existing\chanel-reinvent-ui-db2\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\connections\index.js:62
      throw new Error(msg);
      ^

Error: Unknown adapter "sails-db2" for connection `default`.  You should double-check that the connection's `adapter` property matches the name of one of your adapters.  Or perhaps you forgot to include your "sails-db2" adapter when you called `waterline.initialize()`...
```

Comment: There is no simple answer here.  You have to first make sure all 3rd party modules you are usingexplicitly support node v16 and upgrade them to their latest version.  If you're sure they all do support v16, then you just have to test your program thoroughly and dive into an errors you find to see what's causing it.  It could be something changed in nodejs or, more likely, something sketchy/unsupported you were doing before that no longer "happens" to work.

Comment: This [sails-db2](https://github.com/IbuildingsItaly/sails-db2#readme) module, shows in its package.json ` "node": ">=6.9.1",` but that doesn't necessarily  mean they've tested their stuff with the most recent versions of nodejs.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest that after you upprade your version of nodejs, you reinstall all third party modules, definitely waterline and sales-db2.  The details of the error its reporting also make it sounds like something might not be installed properly.